# Tracking data offset of data in a table to retrieve the previous/next subset on table scroll

Tags: java, sqlite, gwt

I am writing a browser based application using GWT and making use of websql (yes, I know it is deprecated). I have created a custom table widget (based on FlexTable) and enabled it to scroll with the help of some CSS trickery. What I am striving to achieve (without much success) is that when the user scrolls to the start/end of the current data in the table, an event is fired and the next subset of X rows is returned from the websql DB and replaces the data currently in the table. In order for this to work, I need to keep track of the data offset in the table widget so that I can pass this to the query and use the limit and offset functions of SQL to return the required data. However, I just cannot seem to get the logic right to implement the data offset tracker within the widget. Another complication is that I need the table to be able to scroll 'into the past' (so to speak), so that it can retrieve data from before the initial start point when the table loads.

I have been at this for a number of days now and just cannot seem to get it right. So I was wondering/hoping that someone might be able to point me in the right direction (PLEASE!).

Thanks in advance

Tim

Comment: @nKn Seems like I have tried everything! Ok, well I am able to capture UP scrolls and DOWN scrolls, that bit is pretty straight forward. The different variations of logic that I have tried all seem to work except for about 10% of situations, which is very frustrating. Currently I am using a combination of currentScrollDirection, previousScrollDirection and the dataCursor to work out what action needs to be taken. Whichever variation I have tried, it is always the logic that deals with the zero boundary that causes me problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is causing a problem.

```
int page = 0;

// when you hit the bottom
page++;
loadData(page);

// when you hit the top
if (page > 0) {
    page--;
    loadData(page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim I think it is not a good idea controlling the scroll with CSS trickery.

I have done something similar soon and controlling all the logic (pagination, scroll positions,...).

What I suggest to use is a gwt's scrollPanel, a `HasData` widget (like a cellList) your custom `AbstractCell` (class which is rendered for each row of your list) and `asyncDataProvider` ( which gives you the `onRangeChange` handler for asking to your server when the range data display has changed).

You can force/fire that event when in scrollPanel.addScrollHandler detects you are arriving to the end.

If you want to see all of this in action have a look into (click on source code): http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

EDIT [according comment below]:

A. If you want to override the data (in the example is X+X+X...) with the new retrieved just maintain always the same range of data displayed [`display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize);`], and start from 0 when  you render the new data (on your `RangeChange` listener).

B. If you need to have control over up and down scrolls instead of taking advantage of the used events internally on the cellList (basically `onRangeChange`), you can create your custom events and fire them (this option could be easier for your colleagues for understanding everything). And do not worry about controlling up and down scrolls, inside the `ShowMorePagerPanel.java` you can see a simple example of knowing up and down controls.

Anyway, I did not explain more detailed because I did not see you very convinced to use `CellList` approach (and I was using my tablet :D ).

If you change your mind, just let me know and I write for you a proper example step by step (this part could be tricky, so if you are lost it is normal ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I understand what you are saying and thank you for the link to the example. However, my situation differs slightly in that when the next set of data is retrieved, the current set of data in the table is replaced by the new. I therefore only ever have X rows in the table, rather than X+X+X... etc. This therefore makes keeping track of the data more complex as I need to consider UP scrolls as well as DOWN scrolls.